# How do I run ambient operations on databases for a consumer-facing app?

Tags: android, ios

Let's say I want to build a shopping list app. Users can add or remove items from their list, and those changes will be synced across all of their devices. The backend required to support this app is obviously quite simple.

But say I want to build an additional feature that uses machine learning to study the user's purchasing patterns and automatically includes any items that the user might've forgotten to include for that week. In general terms, how would I go about doing this? How could I get a machine learning algorithm to execute in the background without necessarily having to wait for any user input?

Comment: You wouldn't run it on the device.  You'd run it on your servers, or at least train it on your servers.  You'd also be really, really careful to message the user-  the first time an app bought something automatically for me I didn't ask for, the app would not only be deleted, I'd be reporting you to the state for fraud.  You'd be better off asking the user if they want it if you have VERY high confidence.

Comment: Actually as a second thought-  you may also be setting yourself up for a lot of losses.  In the US, if an item is not requested but is shipped the receiver is neither legally obligated to pay or return it.  They legally get it as a freebie.  https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0181-unordered-merchandise

Comment: Hi Gabe, thanks so much for your interest in helping me out here. The example I provided was actually just a hypothetical intended to clarify my question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all is this query for a POC app or a full blown production app. Because the answers would differ based on the same.

Anyways for a POC app, you can use Firebase for the first part of your problem i.e to maintain an online shopping list for an user which is synched to multiple devices. Essentially you would be using `Firebase Authentication` and `Firebase Realtime database` to achieve the same (I have done the exact same thing for an app i developed recently purely for academic purpose). Firebase database is basically well structure JSON document and how well it scales depends on how well the developer structures the data.

Now for the second part of your problem, you can try integrating `Google BigQuery`. I  personally have not tried that but you can give it a try.

Comment: What do you think about retrieving the user data from Firebase, performing the machine learning analysis on my end, and pushing the results of that analysis back to Firebase?

Comment: Do you mean analyzing the usage pattern for each user on a device that the user is logged in ? In any case you don't wanna do that because that would add a huge overhead with growing data. Your app might report consuming battery even when the user has not opened it recently which is honestly very annoying. As the other answer has suggested, that will prompt the user in quickly uninstalling your app. Long answer short, don't do things in your app that user does not understand.

Comment: I meant I'd retrieve and analyze the usage pattern for each user on my own device or server and then push those results back to a database that the user's device could then retrieve from

Comment: Yes, fetch the data from the database on a server and run the analysis on it and you can push back some changes to the database based on the same. Try using some hosted solution like `Google BighQuery` before you spin up your own solution